# Добавленный div не смещается вниз JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку добавлялся блок div, внутри которого будут параграфы, но при добавлении они все накладываются друг на друга, что делать? Вот [видео](https://youtu.be/GEZLqSBgnh8).

```
var newcount    = 0;
    var allprice    = 0;
    var btnn        = $("#submit_btn");
    var form        = $(".formselect");
        form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var product_id          = $(".info").data("product_id");
        var product_name        = $(".info").data("product_name");
        var price               = $(".info").data("product_price");
        var quantity            = $("#sel1").val();
        newprice                = allprice + (price * quantity );
        allprice                = newprice
        newcount++;
        $(".count_of_quantity").html(quantity)
        $(".count").html(newcount);
        $(".product-name").html(product_name);
        $("#price").html(newprice);

        console.log("*****")
        console.log(allprice)
        console.log("*****")
        console.log(newprice)
        $(".basket-item").append("<div class='deleteblock'>" 
                                    + "<p class='goods'>" + "Goods:" + "<span class='product-name'>" +  product_name + "</span>" + "</p>" 
                                    + "<p class='quantity'>" + "Quantity" +"<span class='count_of_quantity'></span>" + "</p>"
                                    + "<a href='#' class='deleteitem'>X</a>"
                                + "</div>");
    })
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CSS код, он разбросан, и там много где очень стоит !important, так много, потому что не смог перебить bootstrap

```
.basket-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 39px;
    right: -80px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 100;
    z-index: 3333;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden; 

    border-top: 1px solid #27E760;
}

.basket-item li a {
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.basket-item li a:hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
} 

.basket-item p {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0 0 !important;
    margin: 0 0 !important;

}

.basket-item a {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.basket-item a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd !important;
}

.goods {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}


.quantity {
    left: 40%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}


.totalprice {
    top: 35%;
    left: 0%;


}

.posss {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    right: -20px;
}

.deleteitem {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 80%;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 100;

}
```

Comment: Проблема не в JS. Добавьте код css классов.

Comment: well done! dsadsda

Comment: Может проблема в этом ".basket-item p {
    position: absolute;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто смени div на ul и li вот к примеру

```
$(".basket-item ul").append('<li class="del">' + '<span class="goods">Goods:' + product_name  + '</span>' 
            + '<span class="quantity"> Quantity:' + '<span class="count_of_quantity">' + quantity + '</span>' + '</span>' 
            + '<a href="#" class="deleteitem">X</a>' + '<span class="hidden del_price">'+ full_price_per_item + '</span>' +  "</li>");
            },
```